# Invalid white space character (0xe) in text to output

Tags: xml, soap, odata

I have published an OData service for a table called Tickets.
I see that parsing goes wrong at http://localhost:8080/odata/ticket_odata/Tickets?$skip=39947.
I got this error message;

```
XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: file:///C:/Users/sk/AppData/Local/Temp/Tickets-3
Line Number 757, Column 34:
Temperatures vary between 80 and <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><code>500</code><message xml:lang="en-US">Exception occurred while processing OData request.</message></error>
---------------------------------^
```

I also get this stacktrace;

```
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid white space character (0xe) in text to output (in xml 1.1, could output as a character entity)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeCharacters(BaseStreamWriter.java:469)
    at akka.stream.alpakka.xml.impl.StreamingXmlWriter$$anon$1.onPush(StreamingXmlWriter
```

But when I look into http://localhost:8080/odata/ticket_odata/Tickets?$skip=39946 I see the object where it goes wrong written out completely, the "description" field is written completely while at skip=39947 gives an error.

When looking to the DB i see the last Ticket object ID= 140737488359769, which is returned at http://localhost:8080/odata/ticket_odata/Tickets?$skip=3994.

When looking to the next Ticket object ID = 140737488359770, which NOT could be found. Could trying to find an empty object the cause? or ID not existing?
While I do found the Ticket object ID = 140737488359771.

So my question is at the end what is causing this OData parsing error, how can I fix it? But I do also not know how to inspect the field causing this error, how can I do this?

EDIT1: When I add a record with the missing ID 140737488359770 the parsing goes OKAY. So what is causig the OData to per se want to retrieve the next ID? How could I skip this?

EDIT2: I now receive an other error at http://localhost:8080/odata/ticket_odata/Tickets?$skip=39948

```
'<' hexadecimal value 0x3c is an invalid attribute character
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask two questions:

(1) So my question is at the end what is causing this OData parsing error?

(2) But I do also not know how to inspect the field causing this error, how can I do this?

Regarding question (1), we don't know. Whatever process or workflow was generating this XML has a bug that causes the XML to be ill-formed. There's no way we can diagnose it without knowing something (perhaps everything!) about that process.

Regarding question (2), you need to examine the data using non-XML tools, for example, a hex editor.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, Ticket/id 140737488359769 contained several unreadable characters (rectangles in description) deleting that solved the issue. Looking to the object after the error is given.